# access: passing variables from vba to sql

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i am clicking a button on a form in access:

```
Private Sub Command29_Click()
some_variable = 2
stDocName = "test"
DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName
End Sub
```

my query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [some_table]
WHERE [Occurrence Number]=some_variable;
```

is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only ways to pass a parameter to a select query and to view the results are:

1. Update the SQL of the query to include the parameter
2. Use a form to supply the parameter

In general, option 2 is preferred.

With action queries, you have a lot more options.

EDIT re Comment

```
SELECT *
FROM [some_table]
WHERE [Occurrence Number]=Forms!SomeOpenForm!SomeControl
```

Comment: yes remou, thats the question how do we use a form to supply the parameter?

Comment: If that's the question, then EDIT YOUR QUESTION TO REFLECT WHAT YOU REALLY WANT TO ASK.